# Howler js pause/resume trouble

Tags: javascript, howler.js

I'm using the Howler js library to set a player in an app running through Electron. First everything seemed to work well, but after a few weeks using the app, a bug occurs repeatedly, but not constantly : the `pause()` function doesn't work. Here's some piece of code :

Initialization :

```
    var is_paused = true;
    var currentTrack = "track1";

    var tracks =    {"track1" :  new Howl({urls: ['path/to/track1.mp3']}),
                    "track2" : new Howl({urls: ['path/to/track2.mp3']}),
                    "track3" : new Howl({urls: ['path/to/track3.mp3']})
    };
```

Then I have a few buttons for play/resume, pause, stop, and play a specific track :

```
$('#playS').click(function(){
        if (is_paused){
            tracks[currentTrack].play();
            is_paused = false;
        }
    });

$('#pauseS').click(function(){
        tracks[currentTrack].pause();
        is_paused = true;
    });

$('.trackBtn').click(function(){
        tracks[currentTrack].stop(); 
        currentTrack = $(this).attr('id');
        tracks[currentTrack].play();
        is_paused = false;
    });
```

The problem is that sometimes (generally after 40-45 min of a track playing), the `pause()` function just do nothing, which is really annoying cause I need to pause the track and play another 30 sec file and then resume the current track. I checked the console while the bug occurs, it says absolutely nothing. I have no idea where the bug comes from, there's not a lot of information about how works the library. I really need some help here, thank's in advance.

EDIT : one more thing, when `pause()` doesn't work, if I click `play()` the track plays from the begining, and I have control on this second instance of the track. It's like the first instance has reached end, but still playing.

Comment: I would recommend updating to the latest version, 2.0.0.

Comment: Sorry I've been so long to reply. The update solved the issue indeed, thank's.

Answer (score 4):

Without knowing what version of Howler you're using, or what other code might be messing things up, there is one thing I think might help:  You don't need to track the paused state.  The "playing" method takes care of that.  I've made it work using something like this:

`// If it's paused, it's not playing, so...
paused = !myHowlInstance.playing();`

Another thing I noticed is that you have `currentTrack = $(this).attr('id');` in your (I think it's a) stop button.  Unfortunately I don't know JQuery well enough to know if there's anything wrong with that (I'm more of a Dojo fan myself).  But it looks like `currentTrack` may be set to some value not in your list (which would break `tracks[currentTrack]`).  You might want to go into the console and type `tracks["track1"]`, `currentTrack` etc. to see their values.  You can even do `tracks[currentTrack].play();` and see what happens.  I wasn't sure if you knew you could do that (it was a *huge* help to me when I found out about it).

And as far as the "un-pausing" starting from the beginning, I'm currently struggling with it myself; at this time there's no clear way to do this (no `resume()`, `pause(false)` etc.), and I've seen a few more questions on the subject on Google and SO, so you're not alone.  I've experimented with the `seek` method, but with no luck.  I'll post a comment if/when I reach a breakthrough on that. :)

**EDIT:** I figured out the play-from-beginning thing.  It does involve "seek", and also the whole "instance ID" concept (which I never really understood the importance of from the documentation).

Here's an example from a project I'm working on (also a game); it doesn't involve JQuery (sorry), but it should give you the gist of how to fix the problem.

```
var myBgMusic = new Howl(...);
var myMusicID = myBgMusic.play();   // The docs say play() returns an ID, and I'll be passing that to "seek" later.
var paused = false;
var saveSeek;
function TogglePause() {

    if (paused) {
        myBgMusic.play(myMusicID);
        myBgMusic.seek(saveSeek, myMusicID);
    } else {
        myBgMusic.pause();
        saveSeek = myBgMusic.seek(myMusicID);
    }
};
```

Comment: It doesn't work if we use the option html5=true - HOWLER.Howl({..., html5: true, ...});

Comment: But if we set the server Accept-Ranges:bytes it will work as expected.